# ISDEV fatal error 6032 Internal build error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ant, windows-xp, installshield

i am using IS2008, Windows XP and VS2010. everything was ok until two weeks ago but something happened and everything changed.

I have been having "ISDEV  fatal error 6032 Internal build error" errors recently. I have checked all website but i could not get any answers about this problem. I have no idea why this is happening, I was thinking that my InstallShield had expired, however I did not get any warning message while IS executes.

I am sending logs above,

```
 [exec] Embedding manifest SetupExe.Invoker.manifest into setup.exe
 [exec] **ISDEV : fatal error -6032: Internal build error**
 [exec] Installers\Release 2 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 [exec] Log file has been created: <file:D:\OutpuT\EnterpriseClient\Release\Installers\Release 2\LogFiles\3-1-2013 10-32-00 AM.txt>
```

======
and this is CMD error message:

```
 [exec] Result: -1073741819
 [exec] Result: 1

BUILD FAILED
D:\...\build.xml:26: Following error occured while executing this line
D:\...\build.xml:56: Following error occured while executing this line
D:\...\InstallShield\build.xml:39: Following error occured while executing this line
D:\...\InstallShield\...\build.xml:7: Following error occured while executing this line
D:\...\InstallShield\...\build.xml:107: Following error occured while executing this line
D:\...\InstallShield\...\build.xml:704: Following error occured while executing this line
D:\...\InstallShield\...\build.xml:792: Warning: Could not find file D:\...\OutpuT\EnterpriseClient\Release\Installers\Release 2\DiskImages\DISK1\1028.mst to copy.

Total time: 244 minutes 43 seconds
cmake.pl failed with error : 1
```

I would be happy if someone could share a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem has been resolved,

i could not find anything wrong on my code or on my enviroment then, i decided deactivate our anti virus program (trend micro). i think trend did not let me to access some paths.

fortunately everything looks ok.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll read this, but you should accept your own answer if everything is okay.